# Changing images on multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, image

I have a main sheet with 10 different dropboxes, each of them represent a image (according to selection) that will show on another sheets (Proposta1, Proposta2,...,Proposta10).

For example, in sheet Proposta1, there will be one image1, that was select according to the dropbox selection on the main sheet. In sheet Proposta10, there will be image1, image2,...,image10, again according to dropbox selection.
I've managed to do this code, which works fine, but I can only make it to change a image on one sheet. What I want is to change that same image on all sheets. See below:

```
If Target.Row = 5 And Target.Column = 4 Then
Worksheets("Proposta1").Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Worksheets("Rolos Compactadores").Range("AH5").Value)
End If
```

I'm new to VBA and coding in general, but I getting there. I also tried to find something similar but I couldn't find somenthing that helped me. Also, sorry if I'm not clear, feel free to ask me whatever you want.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where's the rest of the code? How is this code called/invoked?

Comment: It seems there is no "rest", the rest is what he wants.

Comment: That's just it, actually. According to a selection in the main sheets, It will load a picture, which is located in a folder. What I need is to change that same image (lets say Image1), on all others sheets. Where is = 'Workskeets("Proposta1")', I would like to, somehow, change Proposta2, 3, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
For Each ws in Worksheets
    If Left(Trim(ws.name),8) = "Proposta" Then
        If Target.Row = 5 And Target.Column = 4 Then
            ws.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Worksheets("Rolos Compactadores").Range("AH5").Value)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Hope this help.